# How to debug "cannot open output file allocating memory.exe: Permission denied" in C++?

Tags: c++

I am learning how to allocate memory. This code is suppose to prompt the user to input some values and then print the values out, and the sum of all those values. But the code only prints the values out. It does not print out the sum. I am using ECLIPSE to run this code and whenever I try to run it, I get the message "error exist in this code. Do you want to continue launching?". I can't find the error.

Here is the message I get whenever I run it. PS the file name is allocating memory.

```
15:12:29 **** Incremental Build of configuration Debug for project allocating memory ****
Info: Internal Builder is used for build
g++ -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -o "src\\allocating memory.o" "..\\src\\allocating memory.cpp" 
g++ -o "allocating memory.exe" "src\\allocating memory.o" 
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/6.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot open output file allocating memory.exe: Permission denied
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Here is the code.thanks

```
 #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;

    int main() {
        int i, j, sum = 0 ;
        int *p;

        cout<<"how many numbers do you want to input"<<endl;
                cin>> i;

            p =new (nothrow)int [i];
            if (p== nullptr){

                cout<<"Sorry not enough memory to allocate for this program"<<endl;}
            else {
                for (j=0; j<i; j++){
                cout<<"enter the numbers then "<<endl;
                cin>> p[j];}
            // to print the numbers

                cout << "the numbers you entered are"<<endl;
                    for (j=0; j<i;j++){
                        cout << p[j]<< "," << endl;
                        sum +=p[j];
                        cout << "the sum of all the inputs are"<< sum ;
                    }

                    delete[] p;
            }
        return 0;
    }
```

***** update***

Here is a better attempt to this question and it works. I am trying to dynamically allocate memory for the inputs from the user, print out those input and find their sums. Here is the code.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int i, j, sum = 0 ;
    int *p;

    cout<<"how many numbers do you want to input"<<endl;
            cin>> i;

        p =new (nothrow)int [i];
        if (p== nullptr){

            cout<<"Sorry not enough memory to allocate for this program"<<endl;}
        else {
            for (j=0; j<i; j++){
            cout<<"enter the numbers then "<<endl;
            cin>> p[j];}
        // to print the numbers

            cout << "the numbers you entered are"<< endl;
                for (j=0; j<i;j++){
                    cout << p[j]<< ",";
                    sum = sum + p[j];
                }
                cout << endl;
            cout << "The sum of these numbers is " << sum<< endl;



                delete[] p;
        }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is the compilation error?

Comment: You know what is a *really good* tool for telling you what's wrong with C++ code? A compiler. What did it tell you was wrong with it?

Comment: There's no `=+` operator.

Comment: this looks suspicious too. "p =new (nothrow)int [i];"

Comment: @molbdnilo: Indeed, there is no such operator. But where did you find "`=+` operator" in the code?

Comment: Iam using ECLIPSE and it says " cannot open output file [myfilename'exe]". permission denied"

Comment: @AnT There's an attempt to use it in the line that says `sum =+ p[j];`.

Comment: @Biffen so what do you advice? That is what i though at first so i restarted it and i still have the same message

Comment: @molbdnilo: Nope, there isn't. That is just `=` operator followed by unary `+` operator. Obviously, it does not do what the OP wanted it to do, but it is still perfectly correct from the language point of view. There's no `=+` operator in this code. With the same degree of success you can point at `cout << p[j]<< "," << endl;` and state that "there's no `]<<` operator".

Comment: I'm not sure what Eclipse is complaining about. There should be no problem compiling that.

Comment: @TINA15 Could it be that you're still running you're program while trying to compile (well, link) it?

Comment: @Biffen i am not sure what you mean.

Comment: @TINA15 If you're executing the exe Windows won't let you overwrite it when you try to link it again. I believe that's the error message you'd see if that was the case.

Comment: @Biffen So what you mean is that, i am running the code while it is still running?

Comment: @TINA15 No, that you're *compiling and linking* the code while it is still running. But that's just one of many possibilities.

Comment: Completely transforming your question and invalidating answers in the process is strongly discouraged. If you have made some progress and encountered another problem, please post it as a new question.

Comment: Ok @Quentin. Thanks for that. I will do that.

Answer (score 2):

You have a typo around the += operator.

```
sum =+ p[j];
```

It should be:

```
sum += p[j];
```

Comment: oh thanks!! i will make the change